# Syntactic error in jquery-1.11.0.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

In prestashop, jqzoom doesnt work and I am looking for a error, I found this error in jquery-1.11.0.min.js, but I didn't modify it:

```
 unrecognized expression: input[@type=radio].star
```

How can I solve it?

This is the code of jqzoom that doesn't work:

```
{if $jqZoomEnabled}
     <a href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'thickbox_default')}" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" 
     title="{$image.legend|htmlspecialchars}" rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 
     'large_default')}'">
     <img id="thumb_{$image.id_image}" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'medium_default')}" 
     alt="{$image.legend|htmlspecialchars}"  />
     </a>
{else}
     <a href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'thickbox_default')}" rel="other-views" 
     class="thickbox {if $smarty.foreach.thumbnails.first}shown{/if}" title="{$image.legend|htmlspecialchars}">
     <img id="thumb_{$image.id_image}" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'medium_default')}" 
     alt="{$image.legend|htmlspecialchars}"  />
     </a>
{/if}
```

Comment: the "@" is no longer supported by jquery (searching around i've find it), so the problem should be there, BUT, you say you havn't change anything there... i'm thinkinking about something like: have you linked also the migration plugin of jquery (I mean that library that helps older jquery scripts to work with newer ones)

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
this

Comment: Where i should link that in Prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

try using the migrate plugin:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin
it works by itself, enalbing old and deprecated functions.

Comment: Ok, i have downloaded and now is in my folder js/jquery.
but, in with archive have i to include the references:
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: well, now is up to mh...maybe editing the theme? my sugestion is to 1) open the page on which you have tr issue.
2) check if there is the migrate plugin, after the jquery inlcude.
3) if not, well, it's a matter of find wich tpl file in the theme folder should have the jquery include code, and add the migration code as well. take a look at the header.tpl, joquery should be there.

Comment: jquery migrate is loaded in the page, and also jquery 1.11 min. but the error is in jquery 1.11.

Comment: The problems is the **productcoment module**, disable it and works fine, but now i need add comments to my products :(

Can you help me?